# NLTK Classifier Object

Tags: python, nltk

I am getting memory error when training the classifier for the whole data set so I divided the data set into small parts and training an individual classifier object for each.

For testing I need a combination of these individual classifier object. So how can I do that. I can store the objects in the pickle file, but then again they will be individual objects only.

I am using NLTK.

Code :

```
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
         for category in movie_reviews.categories()
         for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

all_words = []
for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)
    return features



#print((find_features(movie_reviews.words('neg/cv000_29416.txt'))))
featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]
numtrain = int(len(documents) * 90 / 100)
training_set = featuresets[:numtrain]
testing_set = featuresets[numtrain:]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classifier needs to be trained on the whole data set (the training_set in your code) for you to be able to make correct predictions and tests (on the testing_set), since training more than one classifiers with parts of the dataset will not work - or at least it will not be the optimal solution. I would suggest the following things:

1. Try to solve the memory error (if you are running on windows and python 32 bit take a look at this: http://gisgeek.blogspot.gr/2012/01/set-32bit-executable-largeaddressaware.html)
2. Try to optimize your code/ data and maybe use less features, or represent them in a more space/memory efficient way.
3. If 1 and 2 don't work and want to combine many classifier objects to one (but only when it comes to their predictions), you could try ensemble methods BUT I really believe that this is besides the point of what you are trying to do and is not going to fix the issue you are facing. In any case, here's an example of a MaxVote classifier:
   https://bitbucket.org/roadrunner_team/large-scale-sentiment-analysis/src/a06d51ef42325293f0296270ca975341c847ab9f/SentimentAnalysis/FigurativeTextAnalysis/models/Classifier_.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

   ```
   class MaxVoteClassifier(object):
       """
           Takes as input a list of pre-trained classifiers and calculates the Frequency Distribution of their predictions
       """
       def __init__(self, classifiers):
           self._classifiers = classifiers
           self.predictions = None

       def classify(self, tweet_fea):
           counts = FreqDist()
           for classifier in self._classifiers:
               classifier.set_x_trial([tweet_fea])
               counts[classifier.predict()[0]] += 1

           return counts.max()
   ```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. The question is I get Memory error when I exceed just 3000 words, and for correct prediction I need to use the whole data set, which will amount to more than 100k words. So I don't think `point 1 and 2` will work. What I feel is that my problem should be a very common one as most people doing machine learning project must be facing this. This site http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ has made an application using NLTK and it works perfectly, so there must be a common technique or something which everyone must be using.

Comment: The repository in my example is a sentiment analysis project that uses (in one of the settings) ~100000 tweets for train data and ~ 20000 for test data and it is done in a single step without any memory issues. It is using scikit-learn though (and nltk for other things). This is why I proposed 1 and 2. Could you tell me more about where you are testing your example? (Hardware and set up)

Comment: I have a 6GB RAM using the NLTK toolkit of course, and like everything as in the normal computer. Not using scikit module BTW. But since the link I posted is not using scikit module and built on NLTK so I don't think it should make any difference.

Comment: Like it is not even taking the `movie_review` corpora completely. If you want I can show the full code and you can test in any system which has NLTK installed. As I am not using anything from outside in that code.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried your example and it reaches about 6.15 GB of RAM. After some digging around I found this http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html and I am currently trying the apply_features solution. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: Can you try modifying your code like this?: 
       `...
        word_features = list(all_words.keys())
        ... 
        from nltk.classify import apply_features
    
        training_set = apply_features(find_features, documents[:numtrain])
        testing_set = apply_features(find_features, documents[numtrain:])
    
        classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)`

Comment: It worked for me. RAM was down to ~ 300+ MB with the whole dataset. Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Okay, let me check

Comment: Yes @mkaran it is working on the full `movie_data` set. So, my original data set is much more bigger than this corpora, how large a file do you think can the program support given normal RAM systems. Because there must be some way otherwise how do people use NLTK when the data set is 100 times more than this corpora. Do you know about any such methods used.

Comment: I am glad it worked! I guess lazy loading (apply_features uses lazy loading) is one way to avoid loading everything in memory at once. And once the classifier is trained, you could save your model with pickle or joblib (I prefer the latter) to a file which will be more memory-efficient to load and use afterwards. At least that's what I have done when I need to use a classifier on a system that has less ram than I would hope for.